# Is it possible to Let and Get with different data types in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, class, oop

I'm currently working on an Excel VBA Add-In to process a CSV export from one system into the format the stakeholders would like to view it in. I'm fairly new to OOP, but I thought it might be possible to convert priority types within the Let code and have the data stored in the same format it will be output in.

I've written the following class:

```
'Class Module "Project"
Option Explicit

Private m_sPriority As String

Property Let Priority(lInput As Long)
    Select Case lInput
        Case 1
            m_sPriority = "High"
        Case 2
            m_sPriority = "Medium"
        Case 3
            m_sPriority = "Low"
        Case Else
            m_sPriority = "No Priority"
    End Select
End Property

Property Get Priority() As String
    Priority = m_sPriority
End Property
```

And this is the module to test it:

```
'Standard Module
Option Explicit

Sub test()
        Dim Project As Project
        Set Project = New Project

        Project.Priority = 1
        Debug.Print Project.Priority
End Sub
```

I would expect to see "High" output to the console when running this.

Is there a way to accomplish this in VBA, or alternately, is my code malformed?

Comment: Ping! I've edited my short answer to add more info. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your code is malformed. For whatever it's worth, you can't do that in .NET either - the syntax makes it rather unambiguous, whether in C#:

```csharp
private string _priority;
public string Priority 
{
    get { return _priority; }
    private set { _priority = value; }
}
```

...or in VB:

```vb
Private _priority As String
Public Property Priority() As String
    Get
        Return _priority
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        _priority = value
    End Set
End Property
```

A property is either a `Long` or a `String`, it can't be both. `Get`/`Let`/`Set` accessors must be consistent, in VBA as well.

You can **cheat** by losing *type safety* and early binding, by making your property a `Variant`... but that's not really a good way to get started with OOP ;-)

```
Public Enum PriorityLevel
    NoPriority = 0
    HighPriority
    MediumPriority
    LowPriority
End Enum

Private Type InstanceState
    Priority As PriorityLevel
    '...
End Type

Private this As InstanceState

Public Property Get Priority() As Variant
    Priority = PriorityName(this.Priority)
End Property

Public Property Let Priority(ByVal value As Variant)
    this.Priority = value
End Property

Private Function PriorityName(ByVal value As PriorityLevel) As String
    Select Case value
        Case HighPriority
            PriorityName = "High"
        Case MediumPriority
            PriorityName = "Medium"
        Case LowPriority
            PriorityName= "Low"
        Case Else
            PriorityName= "Undefined"
    End Select
End Function
```

While this works perfectly fine and looks pretty neat on the surface, consuming this class when you haven't written it is definitely going to be surprising: if you *set* (`Let`) a `Long`, you rightfully expect to `Get` a `Long` too. This class is begging for a `PriorityName` get-only property:

```
Public Property Get Priority() As PriorityLevel
    Priority = this.Priority
End Property

Public Property Let Priority(ByVal value As PriorityLevel)
    this.Priority = value
End Property

Public Property Get PriorityName() As String
    Select Case this.Priority
        Case HighPriority
            PriorityName = "High"
        Case MediumPriority
            PriorityName = "Medium"
        Case LowPriority
            PriorityName = "Low"
        Case Else
            PriorityName = "Undefined"
    End Select
End Property
```

Now, the benefits of early binding and type safety (whatever little of it you get to leverage in VBA) are immediately apparent: when you write code that assigns the `Priority` property of an object of this type, *IntelliSense* for the `Enum` type guides the writing of the expression:

[image: available enum members appear in a dropdown list]

Moreover, the `Enum` is *abstracting* the underlying numeric value, which becomes irrelevant: instead of a magic hard-coded `1`, the code now says `HighPriority`. Also, the `Get` accessor is as simple as it gets, which is very good: a `Get` accessor should never raise any errors, so the simpler, the better.

Morale of the story: don't hack around type safety if you can help it, do everything you can to keep your code early-bound - avoid `Object` and `Variant` as much as possible; cast `Object` to a known class/interface everywhere you can.

For example prefer this:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
' Workbook.Worksheets(index) returns Object; casting it to Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1").Value = 42
```

To this:

```
' "Range("A1").Value" is entirely late-bound. Beware of typos!
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = 42
```

Comment: I /really/ like this solution, thank you for the update!